# Why does this code work in Vista but not 7?

Tags: java, windows-7, windows-vista, toolkit, screen-resolution

For some reason every time I have someone run this program in Vista it works flawlessly but as soon as I move it over to a Windows 7 PC it stops in the middle of the ActionListener's Action Performed Method meaning I can click my choices but it will never say size selected.
Is there any way to fix this?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class SizerFrame extends JFrame {
    ButtonGroup buttons = new ButtonGroup();
    JTextField width = new JTextField(2);
    JTextField height = new JTextField(2);
    double inchesPerTimeline = 2.1;
    public SizerFrame()
    {
        super("Timeline Application");
        Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(screen.width/2-125,screen.height/2-90,250,180);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        int[] gridX = new int[]{0,0,0,0};
        int[] gridY = new int[]{0,1,2,3};
        int[] gridW = new int[]{1,1,2,5};
        String[] titles = new String[]{"6\"","9\"","10\"","Custom"};
        String[] actions = new String[]{"6","9","10","C"};
        for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)
        {
            JRadioButton current = new JRadioButton(titles[a]);
            current.setActionCommand(actions[a]);
            c.gridx = gridX[a];
            c.gridy = gridY[a];
            c.gridwidth = gridW[a];
            buttons.add(current);
            getContentPane().add(current,c);
        }
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        String[] title = new String[]{"      ","Width","Height"};
        gridX = new int[]{9,10,12};
        for (int a = 0; a< 3; a++)
        {
            c.gridx = gridX[a];
            getContentPane().add(new JLabel(title[a]),c);
        }
        c.gridx = 11;
        getContentPane().add(width,c);
        c.gridx = 13;
        getContentPane().add(height,c);
        c.gridx = 11;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        JButton button = new JButton("Done");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ButtonModel x = buttons.getSelection();
                String size = "XXX";
                System.out.println("Getting screen resolution");
                int screenRes = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution();
                System.out.println("Successfully got screen resolution");
                if (x!=null)
                    size = x.getActionCommand();
                try{
                    TimeTable.width = new Integer(size)*screenRes;
                    TimeTable.height = (int)((TimeTable.titleCount+1)*inchesPerTimeline*screenRes);
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException ex)
                {
                    try{
                        TimeTable.width = (int)(new Double(width.getText().trim())*screenRes);
                        TimeTable.height = (int)(new Double(height.getText().trim())*screenRes);
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException except)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                TimeTable.ready = true;
                System.out.println("Size selected");
                dispose();
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(button,c);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent winEvt){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Concise explanation : 
I have a macro that runs out of Excel in Windows Vista and I tried to distribute it to a Computer running Windows 7. Upon execution the code failed to continue executing after this point i.e. it never printed out the words "Size selected". The rest of the program brings in a csv file from a C:\Users\?\AppData\TimeLineMacroProgram folder and later creates an image in the same directory. But this is the portion of the code that is currently broken.  Whenever the GUI pops up I select the option for 9" and click done which should pass in 9 as a parameter and then print out "Size Selected" but it doesn't it only disposes the window. Please help.

Comment: I can only suspect a bug in the JDK -- are you using exactly the same JDK version in both?

Comment: no considering it's exported as a program to other computers using a class file the only thing like that in question would be the JRE

Comment: Is the program hanging, terminating or erroring out?

Comment: Sorry you're right, I did mean the JRE.

Comment: Add logging, or atleast give us the Java console error messages.  Also, we need to know JRE versions on each machine.

Comment: There was no error that's the thing although that may be the problem itself =/ I had a 
    while(true) loop
in there and I was waiting for this window to execute before continuing

Comment: I got "size selected" on Win7 (commenting out the `TimeTable`s).  Java 7 (beta).

Comment: In order for you to get what I mean I would have to send you the program =( It's too annoying to post up here

Comment: Can you recreate the freeze in a sscce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Longshot guess:

There is an exit from your action listener if width and height text fields don't have content: you return after two NumberFormatExceptions.  This would prevent "Size selected" from being displayed, and not dispose the frame.  If you got the output "Successfully got screen resolution" and then it appeared to stop working, this could possibly be why.  But if you experience that, and then click something else and then Done, it would print size selected.

Comment: @if_zero_equals_one it would disposed be if you didn't return from the actionPerformed method after two NumberFormatExceptions.

Comment: the frame is disposed and nothing else happens =/